# Android: select the strongest wifi access points that is available?

Tags: android

I am trying to display the strongest wifi access point in range which availbe is in my xml file but I am getting something like that",capabilities:[WPA-PSK-CCMP][WPA2-PSK-CCMP][WPS][ESS], level:-59,frequency:2462,timestamp:1083973302545,distance:?(cm),distancceSD:?(cm)" as output if I change "textWifi.setText(a.toString());" to "textWifi.setText(buf.toString());" then I am getting all availabe access point.

How can I pass "buf" in the method "calculateBestAp()" to make it work?

I appreciate any help.

```js
 private void check_wifi_available() {
  WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) this
    .getSystemService(this.WIFI_SERVICE);

  WifiInfo info = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();

  final List<ScanResult> results = wifiManager.getScanResults();

  if (results != null) {
   // StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();
   StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();

   for (int i = 0; i < results.size(); i++) {
    String ssid = results.get(i).SSID;
    if (ssid.startsWith("KD")) {

     buf.append(ssid + "\n");
    }
   }
   
   ScanResult a = calculateBestAP(results);
   textWifi.setText(a.toString());
  }
 }

 private ScanResult calculateBestAP(final List<ScanResult> results) {
  ScanResult bestSignal = null;
  for (ScanResult result : results) {
   if (bestSignal == null
     || WifiManager.compareSignalLevel(bestSignal.level,
       result.level) < 0)
    bestSignal = result;
  }
  return bestSignal;
 }
```

Comment: you may want to clarify the question, are you tying to pass buf to calculateBestAP or textWifi.setText if the later, buf.toString() should be fine.

Comment: I want to pass "buf" to "calculateBestAP" to get  the stongest wifi access point that starts with "KD".

Comment: Does calculateBestAP work the way it is written now, does it return the best signal

Comment: Yes, calaulateBestAo returns the bestSignal.

Comment: if that is the case then you do not need all of the logic that has the stringbuffer, you can just delete it

Comment: I added an answer to explain what I mean by removing the SrtringBuffer logic, also a modification to the calculateBestAP method, but you are saying it works, so you can either use my method or just leave the method the way you have it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//* remove the logic that loops around the StringBuffer, all you need is this logic where you create a new list of all access points with "KD" SSID.

     final List<ScanResult> results = wifiManager.getScanResults();
    if (results != null) {

        ArrayList<ScanResult> updatedResults  = new ArrayList<ScanResult>();
        for (int i = 0; i < results.size(); i++) {
            String ssid = results.get(i).SSID;
            if (ssid.startsWith("KD")) {

                updatedResults.add(results.get(i));
            }
        }
        if(updatedResults.size()>0)
        {
          ScanResult a = calculateBestAP(updatedResults);
          textWifi.setText(a.toString());
       }
    }
}


//* you can modify this method or just leave the original code as is if it works for you

private ScanResult calculateBestAP(ArrayList<ScanResult> results) {
        ScanResult bestSignal = (ScanResult)results.get(0);
        for (int i = 1; i < results.size(); i++) 
        {
            ScanResult result = (ScanResult)results.get(i);
            bestSignal = (WifiManager.compareSignalLevel(bestSignal.level, result.level) < 0) ? result : bestSignal;
        }
        return bestSignal;
    }
```

Comment: I need the logic, to pick the wifi access points which starts with these charachters"KD". Therefore, I have to pass the "buf" variable and not the "results" to the "calculateBestAP" method.

Comment: do you still need to calculate the best signal of all of the wifi access points that starts with "KD"

Comment: Yes, I need that it is necessary for the system.

Comment: ok, save updated answer, where you create a new list of all access points that have "KD" characters and pass them to the caculateBestAP method

Comment: I am getting this error at this line "List<ScanResults> updatedResults  = new List<ScanResults>();"  ==>"Multiple markers at this line
 - ScanResults cannot be resolved to a 
  type
 - ScanResults cannot be resolved to a 
  type
 - Cannot instantiate the type 
  List<ScanResults>" . After I changed it to" List<ScanResult> updatedResults  = new List<ScanResult>();" I am getting "Cannot instantiate the type List<ScanResult>"

Comment: Does the error say why it can not instantiate it, would you print several lines of the error

Comment: The second error at this line "private ScanResult calculateBestAP(final List<ScanResult> results)"==> "This method must return a result of type ScanResult"

Comment: there was one extra bracket that caused the last error, I have just updated it

Comment: no it does not say something else why it cant instantiate "updateResults"

Comment: the second error is solved by delteing the extra brackets but I am still getting the first error "Cannot instantiate the type List<ScanResult>" at this line " List<ScanResult> updatedResults  = new List<ScanResult>();"

Comment: changed the logic to use ArrayList and pass the arraylist to the calculateBestAP method, see if this solves the issue, make sure import java.util.ArrayList;
is included